# Fully Modular Power Supply Replacement

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

When it comes to replacing a fully modular power supply, does anyone know if its a good idea to unplug the cables that go into the supply and plug them back into the new one? Instead of having to unplug both ends of the connectors from the power supply and the motherboard itself?

Most people will tell you to unplug the connectors both from the PSU and the motherboard since they PSU's that are not modular, I guess its for safety reasons when it comes to electricity. So I'm wondering if its a good idea to do what I've mentioned earlier.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If it is the exact same model power supply as the one you are replacing OK.
Otherwise the pin-out of the connectors could be different.  Putting 5v where a 12v or ground should be ends in disaster.

Comment: Agreed. In my personal experience I've seen a single manufacturer of modular PSUs use _three_ dfferent pinouts for the PSU end of the drive cables (4-pin Molex/SATA). They all mechanically interchange, too. "Disaster" would not be too strong a word for the possible outcome. In other words - it is by far safer to pull the old PSU and its cables, and replace them with the new PSU and the cables that came with the new PSU.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan is absolutely right. I have smoked a few Dells because their power supplies are wired differently. Beware.